# Can't connect github account in application deploy tab

Tags: github, heroku, discord

I was using Heroku to host my Discord bot but when i try to connect my github account in the application deploy tab it shows an error message just saying "Item could not be retrieved: Internal Server Error". I already tried to change browsers go to incognito mode but nothing seems to work...

Comment: Please remember to search before asking a new question. See [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Check out:

https://help.heroku.com/A1BZM6QC/why-do-i-see-item-could-not-be-updated-retrieved-unknown-error-on-the-dashboard

https://namespaceit.com/blog/items-could-not-be-retrieved-internal-server-error-heroku-and-github

And if icongnito dosen’t work, try to clear cache or try a different browser